# how to get source of img tags inside a web link with beautiful soup 4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I`m trying to get the src link of img tags inside a website and print them in console

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r = requests.get("https://welovemanga.one/2777/92578/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
thumbnail_elements = soup.find_all("img", class_ = "chapter-img")

for element in thumbnail_elements:
    print(element['src'])
```

the images in this website has a class "chapter-img" with each having its own src link, which is what I want.

[image]

But when I run the code, it returns this for each image in the link:

[image]

How can I get only the src of the img tags insted of lazy_loading.gif ?

Comment: The src of the img tags is being changed by some JS after the page has loaded, the source does not contain the updated values. You'll need to use some kind of browser driver/emulator to scrape the site instead, Selenium is a popular choice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual image link is in the `data-original` attribute but it has to be accessed via proxy, so they set the `src` as the loading gif (that you kept getting) until they have fetched the image and can update `src`. But you can form that link for fetching the actual page image by altering your code to:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r = requests.get("https://welovemanga.one/2777/92578/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
thumbnail_elements = soup.find_all("img", class_ = "chapter-img")
proxyRoot = 'https://welovekai.com/proxy.php?link='

for element in thumbnail_elements:
    print(proxyRoot+''.join(element['data-original'].split()))
```

[There's some whitespaces breaking up the link, so `split`ting and then `join`ing cleans it up.]

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r = requests.get("https://welovemanga.one/2777/92578/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
thumbnail_elements = soup.select("img[data-original]")

for element in thumbnail_elements:
    print(
        "https://welovekai.com/proxy.php?link="
        + element["data-original"].replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "")
    )
```

Prints:

```
https://welovekai.com/proxy.php?link=https://ihlv1.xyz/images2/20220914/ec494844bf563848fce377bbac9d3bda02.jpg&site=mm2r.net
https://welovekai.com/proxy.php?link=https://ihlv1.xyz/images2/20220914/c30814d84e53a829bd9df51c5172fbea03.jpg&site=mm2r.net
https://welovekai.com/proxy.php?link=https://ihlv1.xyz/images2/20220914/356e0b2a3136e9e96dfb45e853b59d8804.jpg&site=mm2r.net
https://welovekai.com/proxy.php?link=https://ihlv1.xyz/images2/20220914/9dd38d6c86ea251f7c94a8068159ef5005.jpg&site=mm2r.net
https://welovekai.com/proxy.php?link=https://ihlv1.xyz/images2/20220914/2abc410ebd0b20a616259d8cb97346dd06.jpg&site=mm2r.net
https://welovekai.com/proxy.php?link=https://ihlv1.xyz/images2/20220914/9c0a6b7bb3074492ee60d231ae5c274707.jpg&site=mm2r.net
https://welovekai.com/proxy.php?link=https://ihlv1.xyz/images2/20220914/42311919da2dfe95d84bcbcfe04e7ef908.jpg&site=mm2r.net
https://welovekai.com/proxy.php?link=https://ihlv1.xyz/images2/20220914/d9597e5c42062aaa985d30bf04c1228a09.jpg&site=mm2r.net
https://welovekai.com/proxy.php?link=https://ihlv1.xyz/images2/20220914/6c1506e7eb266d61704d4b12d382175c10.jpg&site=mm2r.net
https://welovekai.com/proxy.php?link=https://ihlv1.xyz/images2/20220914/81dd5dfe2b3f9342d7844bae1bfd0e7511.jpg&site=mm2r.net
https://welovekai.com/proxy.php?link=https://ihlv1.xyz/images2/20220914/4569ec54e73e6fbfde5bba34efeb03cc12.jpg&site=mm2r.net
https://welovekai.com/proxy.php?link=https://ihlv1.xyz/images2/20220914/5561070bf5ba4c60a6361ea0a2ea5f5413.jpg&site=mm2r.net
https://welovekai.com/proxy.php?link=https://ihlv1.xyz/images2/20220914/eb750f3fa928772123bfd79caee9417c14.jpg&site=mm2r.net
https://welovekai.com/proxy.php?link=https://ihlv1.xyz/images2/20220914/96eaed5a915a569c2a4801eb4cb6305d15.jpg&site=mm2r.net
https://welovekai.com/proxy.php?link=https://ihlv1.xyz/images2/20220914/d922922310736e03e2b2d29301257d9e16.jpg&site=mm2r.net
https://welovekai.com/proxy.php?link=https://ihlv1.xyz/images2/20220914/c3256b2c7b0fa0ee1e21c2dacab79d7b17.jpg&site=mm2r.net
https://welovekai.com/proxy.php?link=https://ihlv1.xyz/images2/20220914/fc7d0d602d0a6af29e7a860ed755304318.jpg&site=mm2r.net
https://welovekai.com/proxy.php?link=https://ihlv1.xyz/images2/20220914/438d5e604808145a5a6cc938f77310b719.jpg&site=mm2r.net
https://welovekai.com/proxy.php?link=https://ihlv1.xyz/images2/20220914/a3e046e32b66eb48d71a1256a6ba867e20.jpg&site=mm2r.net
https://welovekai.com/proxy.php?link=https://ihlv1.xyz/images2/20220914/1469b4a25095ccba7590f4ae0e9cb57221.jpg&site=mm2r.net
https://welovekai.com/proxy.php?link=https://ihlv1.xyz/images2/20220914/4fbf57627d2738b7229fc5b71f18215a22.jpg&site=mm2r.net
https://welovekai.com/proxy.php?link=https://ihlv1.xyz/images2/20220914/a71fc439dc40716fbfd8f570565f80bf23.jpg&site=mm2r.net
https://welovekai.com/proxy.php?link=https://ihlv1.xyz/images2/20220914/3a49068b55e340b703722bdd61912c4924.jpg&site=mm2r.net
https://welovekai.com/proxy.php?link=https://ihlv1.xyz/images2/20220914/30356fd4bbcf29f820f0659f48a7dc5a25.jpg&site=mm2r.net
https://welovekai.com/proxy.php?link=https://ihlv1.xyz/images2/20220914/23f35eba985165d6ca2f24d56c12d3be26.jpg&site=mm2r.net
https://welovekai.com/proxy.php?link=https://ihlv1.xyz/images2/20220914/88a2f7c73927cd1ec22bf09134c6930427.jpg&site=mm2r.net
https://welovekai.com/proxy.php?link=https://ihlv1.xyz/images2/20220914/ed13005b950bcdd4411863aeecdb4c5b28.jpg&site=mm2r.net
https://welovekai.com/proxy.php?link=https://ihlv1.xyz/images2/20220914/dbbb12f95af8242ada32c3040e9e374229.jpg&site=mm2r.net
https://welovekai.com/proxy.php?link=https://ihlv1.xyz/images2/20220914/b75a24be2234dcb6345ac19a83eae68230.jpg&site=mm2r.net
https://welovekai.com/proxy.php?link=https://ihlv1.xyz/images2/20220914/4aa9d31b25db17bf16c7af4962a89c9b31.jpg&site=mm2r.net
https://welovekai.com/proxy.php?link=https://ihlv1.xyz/images2/20220914/0fdf030b478f81bd07fab8e02e3a100232.jpg&site=mm2r.net
https://welovekai.com/proxy.php?link=https://ihlv1.xyz/images2/20220914/288c74bde23a8891c818588eae0bc00b33.jpg&site=mm2r.net
https://welovekai.com/proxy.php?link=https://ihlv1.xyz/images2/20220914/65623e5f600e30df804d9242d3b9ae8c34.jpg&site=mm2r.net
https://welovekai.com/proxy.php?link=https://ihlv1.xyz/images2/20220914/00f9b77c213a7bfe6e52fbdfa1418b6635.jpg&site=mm2r.net
https://welovekai.com/proxy.php?link=https://ihlv1.xyz/images2/20220914/e6ed988baab8eaab2f3949671d6c415536.jpg&site=mm2r.net
https://welovekai.com/proxy.php?link=https://ihlv1.xyz/images2/20220914/da888a2fcff33d94aad4c2a3ffd8c95b37.jpg&site=mm2r.net
https://welovekai.com/proxy.php?link=https://ihlv1.xyz/images2/20220914/0287564880c8564c17232234f484f1ab38.jpg&site=mm2r.net
https://welovekai.com/proxy.php?link=https://ihlv1.xyz/images2/20220914/b6425ffe6bc6df44c61660aac761c03239.jpg&site=mm2r.net
https://welovekai.com/proxy.php?link=https://ihlv1.xyz/images2/20220914/6d221db676c78f6e4bc35d28d40a870040.jpg&site=mm2r.net
https://welovekai.com/proxy.php?link=https://ihlv1.xyz/images2/20220914/b3fef706e4dd4eccc9425113360bb75541.jpg&site=mm2r.net
https://welovekai.com/proxy.php?link=https://ihlv1.xyz/images2/20220914/9026f984ab924b8ac131509900e32efe42.jpg&site=mm2r.net
https://welovekai.com/proxy.php?link=https://ihlv1.xyz/images2/20220914/8dbf0ccdf3827ad85dcac5558228270e43.jpg&site=mm2r.net
https://welovekai.com/proxy.php?link=https://ihlv1.xyz/images2/20220914/c31f203e603905bcdb360301b445d7e644.jpg&site=mm2r.net
```

Comment: thanks, it worked! But why the 2 replaces?

Comment: @Moon The attribute `data-original=` contains some special charts that I don't want to include in the final link.